# How do i convert this sql to a jpa predicate

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

How would I convert this SQL into a jpa predicate?

I have the following tables

**Team**
*id (pk)*

**TeamMember**
*id (pk)
team_id (fk -> Team.id)
user_id (fk -> User.id)*

**User**
*id (pk)*

**Case**
*id (pk)
team_id (fk -> Team.id)*

Given a user id, i want to find out if that user is in a team on a case.

In sql this is easy

```
SELECT c from Case c, TeamMember tm WHERE c.team_id = tm.team_id and tm.user_id = :param_user_Id
```

But how do i create a predicate in jpa for this.

I tried this for Case #1

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
Root rt = cq.from(Case.class);
List<Predicate> predList = new ArrayList<>();
int value = 1;

predList.add(cb.equal(rt.<Team>get("team_id").<TeamMember>get("team_id").<User>get("user_id"), value));
```

but unsurprisingly it doesn't recognise team_id in Team when attempting to join TeamMember

thanks ...

Comment: Split the expressions in order to simplify them: does it work `Path<Team> team = rt.get("team_id")` ? Also post the relevant parts of the Entity definitions. Second hint: use joins, like for example: `Path<TeamMember> teamMember = team.join("team_member_id")`

Comment: I can split them or create joins but it doesn't solve the problem of how do i get from Team to TeamMember when the foreign key is on the wrong side. In the sql it is easy as I don't need the Team table, but with the entity definitions I have to go via Team.

Comment: Also i don't have a .join method on javax.persistence.criteria.Path

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed**

I was not utilising the list in my Team entity definition...

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "team_id")
    private List<TeamMember> team_member_list;
```

So the code is...

```
predList.add(cb.equal(rt.<Team>get("team_id").<List<TeamMember>>get("team_member_list").get("user_id"), value));
```